# Django 404 page not found

Tags: python, django

I've been doing a lesson on udemy trying to make a clone site of producthunt using django.  I've tried asking there, but I don't get an answer.  For some reason when I run the exact same code as the instructor, I get an error when trying to load the page localhost:8000/signup or any other pages other than the home page.

I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySlW7.png)

Settings file:
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQQ4L.png)

Main urls:
[main urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqupb.png)

app urls (named accounts):
[app urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtfpY.png)

views:
[app views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOFep.png)

finally my file structure for reference:
[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GtFF.png)

I've been trying to figure it out with no avail. Any help would be great thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`signup` is a route in the `accounts` app. In your main `urls.py` you include your `accounts.urls` under `accounts/`. Putting that all together, with your current structure you should be hitting `accounts/signup` rather than just `signup`.

Comment: Thank you! That cleared it up. I'm a doofus because it clearly showed that he put accounts/signup in the video.lol

Answer (score 0):

There's no url `/signup` in your web.

You're url is for `accounts/signup/`

Comment: Thank you. This helped me understand urlpatterns more.